# how to call value of an array that was in an array(for java)?

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I have done so far

```
Bidder []Bidlist = new Bidder [3];

Bidlist[0]= new Bidder ("AB111","Bill Chivers");
Bidlist[1]= new Bidder ("AB222","Ric Herbert");    
Bidlist[2]= new Bidder ("AB333","Simon");
```

I can print out the whole array with `System.out.ptint(BidList[1);` however I have no idea how to call the value of index 0 in a index of 0 which is `"AB111"` .

Comment: Override the `public String toString()` method in the `Bidder` class, where you can provide the pattern to which your instances will be represented by String objects.

Comment: please add the code of the class `Bidder`, you probably have a getter there for each field, so you need to use it -> `Bidlist[0].getYourFieldName()`

Comment: is `Bidder ` your class?

Comment: How is your Bidder class implemented ?

Comment: Flagged as closed, since the asker may not have enough knowledge how to use getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is the first parameter of Bidder. I guess Bidder is a modal like that:

```
class Bidder {
    String item;
    String value;

 public Bidder(String item, String value) {
    this.item = item; 
    this.value = value;
 }

 public String getItem() { return this.item; }
 public String getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

Then you can get it by

```
System.out.println(BidList[0].getItem());
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide getters for the Strings you have and access the value

```
  String fieldValue =  Bidlist[0].getYourStringFieldname();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Bidder class you should define define getters and setters for your field names (if you have not already done so).

The you can call those methods on your array objects.

```
    BidList[0].getFirstField();
    BidList[0].getSecondField();
    BidList[0].getThirdField();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bidder []Bidlist = new Bidder [3];

        Bidlist[0]= new Bidder ("AB111","Bill Chivers");
        Bidlist[1]= new Bidder ("AB222","Ric Herbert");    
        Bidlist[2]= new Bidder ("AB333","Simon");
        System.out.println(Bidlist[0].getId());
    }
}



class Bidder{
    String id;
    String name;
    public Bidder(String id,String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```